# Discontinuous functions in partition functions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I am trying to model a system where once the pressure is more than $10kpa$, a door breaks and the volume doubles.

Suppose the following example for a partition function:

$$
Z=\sum_{i=1}^N{e^{-p V(p)}}
$$

where

$$
V(p)=\begin{cases}
2 & p>10\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

We can calculate

$$
\begin{align}
\overline{V}&=-\frac{\partial \ln{Z}}{\partial \beta}=-\frac{1}{Z} \frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta} \\
&=-\frac{1}{Z} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^N{e^{-p V(p)} \left(  -V(p) - \beta V'(p) \right) } \right] \\
&=\frac{1}{Z} \sum_{i=1}^N{e^{-p V(p)} V(p)  } + \frac{1}{Z} \sum_{i=1}^N{e^{-p V(p)}  p V'(p) } \\
\end{align}
$$

The last line is true if the second term is equal to zero and with the exception of $p=10$, it is.

$$
\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{Z} Ne^{-p V(p)} V(p)\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{Z} Ne^{-p2} 2 & p>10\\
\frac{1}{Z} Ne^{-p} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
&=\begin{cases}
 2 & p>10\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

### Questions:

Can this legitimately be a valid partition function?

Considering the following:

A. The partition function is obtained as a result of using the Lagrange multiplier method of optimization where the constraint functions must have continuous derivatives. And $V(p)$ is highly discontinuous.

B. The Lagrangian multiplier is used in the $V(p)$ function it is supposed to be conjugated to. Can these legitimately be used?